# Double dependencies injection and good practices

Tags: java, swing, dependency-injection

Im trying to code an apps in java and i would like to know something about the injections.

I have a class A that inherits from JFrame :

```
public class A extends JFrame {

public A(CModel model){

    B classB = new B(model);
  }
}
```

a class B that inherits from JPanel :

```
public class B extends JPanel {

public CModel model;

public B(CModel model){

    this.model = model;
  }
}
```

For injecting my Model into my B class, i have to inject it into my A class.
Can i do that or is it considered bad practice ?
Do i have other choices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't think it's an issue, as both classes are independent enough to tested separately and with each other, but that's just my opinion. Another level might be to allow `B` to be injected into `A` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your design, class B requires a CModel (good practice is to make model 'final').

Class A *encapsulates* B; so while you could first construct B, and inject B into A, there is no good reason to do this.  The user who creates A does not need to know about B.

Since B requires a CModel, it follows that A requires a CModel.

The way you have done it best describes A because the only 'state' that is required to construct A is the state required by B.